How to replace double slash in URL string with single slash in Python
I've got a URL that contains erroneous double slash(es) ("//") that I need to turn into single slash. Needless to say, I want to leave the double slash after "https:" untouched.
What's the shortest Python code that can make this change in a string?

I've been trying to use re.sub, with the regex with a negation of the colon (viz., [^:](//)) but it wants to replace the whole match (including the preceding non-colon character) and not just the double slash.
Maybe I should just turn all double slashes to single, and then convert the "https:/" to "https://" at the end?

Perhaps an overly simple approach:
new_url = old_url.replace('//', '/').replace(':/', '://')

This is essentially the "turn all double slashes to single, and then convert the https:/ to https:// at the end" approach you suggested.

Right.  It's not necessary to use a regular expression for every text problem.  Unless you're a Perl programmer, but that's a different story.

"Overly simple" is an oxymoron.

What you need is a "negative lookbehind":
url_without_double_slashes = re.sub('(?<!:)//', '/', url)

It checks that the position (before the first / in this case) is not immediately preceded by whatever regex is between (?<! and ) (: in this case).
Syntax of lokaheads and lookbehinds in short:

Positive lookahead: (?=whatever)
Negative lookahead: (?!whatever)
Positive lookbehind: (?<=whatever)
Negative lookbehind: (?<!whatever)

(All have (?, negatives have ! instead of =, lookbehinds have an extra < before = or !)
A particularly safe version of the replacement you need would be the following:
url_1 = re.sub('(?<!^http:)(?<!^https:)//', '/', url)

Unfortunately we cannot write
url_1 = re.sub('(?<!^https?:)//', '/', url)

because this raises an error with message
look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

(see the chapter "Important Notes About Lookbehind" in the page linked above)
